# Telnet hangs with vim

Tags: windows, console, telnet, vim

I'm starting to use telnet for remote access and control of others windows pc. The problem that I'm facing is that when i start the VIM program the telnet session hangs and it doesn't respond to any key press. What is the reason behind that?

Comment: What exactly do you telnet to on Windows client? Do you run the vim in telnet session on Windows client? How is the vim installed?

Comment: i don't understand well your questions. I'm connecting with telnet to a cmd terminal, from what i launch any command line program with out any problem, except VIM. VIM opens, appears the startup screen and then nothing more works

Comment: I, too, am having the same issue. When I am in a telnet session to a Windows 7 box, vim will not open and the telnet session hangs.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this happen when using PuTTy to ssh to a UWIN instance via localhost.

Vim for Windows assumes it is running inside a Windows console window, which is not the case when all you've got is a remote ANSI terminal emulator.